# how to install nodejs and npm on linux and have a working semver module

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, webpack

after trying to update nodejs because there was a problem with the semver module it was not working anymore. searching the internet revealed that there is something wrong with the installation. after removing nodejs as well as npm and installing them again i cannot run npm anymore as the binary is not found.

as far as i can tell there are multiple ways to install nodejs and npm and i am wondering which is the best way. i would prefer a method that does not rely on a package manager. also i might have trace amounts of previous nodejs installations left and i don't know how to get rid of them.

i don't know if this is important, but i need npm for a laravel project that is using vue. without it i would never have touch it.

thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Take a look at [this tutorial](https://letscodepare.com/blog/how-to-install-nvm-node-version-manager-on-linux) on installing nodejs via [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

Comment: thank you very much. i cannot believe this worked. even the npm binary is found again. sadly there are still some permission problems (what a piece of shit), but nodejs and npm are finally installed and working.